# How to set userAgent property in node-phantom?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, user-agent

How can I set custom userAgent property?
I tried to use

> page.set('settings.userAgent','myCustomUserAgent')

But it doesn't seem to work.
I also tried to check the changes via *'page.get'*

> page.get('settings')
> .then(function(settings){
> console.log(settings);
> })
> .catch(function(err){
> console.error(err);
> })

But the only thing I see is:

```
    {
      XSSAuditingEnabled: false,
      javascriptCanCloseWindows: true,
      javascriptCanOpenWindows: true,
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      loadImages: true,
      localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: false,
      userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1',
      webSecurityEnabled: true 
    }
```

Here is my code

```
'use strict';
const async = require('async');
const phantom = require('node-phantom-async');
process.setMaxListeners(Infinity);

const uri = 'http://www.my.uri';

function parseCatalogLinks(callback) {
    phantom.create({
        phantomPath: require('phantomjs').path,
        ignoreSSLErrors: true
    })
        .bind({})
        .then(function (ph) {
            this.ph = ph;
            return this.ph.createPage();
        })
        .then(function (page) {
            this.page = page;
            this.page.set('settings.userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64)' +
                ' AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)' +
                ' Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36');
            return this.page;
        })
        .then(function (page) {
            this.page.get('settings')
                .then(function (settings) {
                    console.log('settings', settings)
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            return this.page.open(uri);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error while opening main page', err);
        })
        .then(function (status) {
            console.info('Main site ' + uri + ' opened with status', status);
        })
        .then(function () {
            return this.page.evaluate(function () {
                var $catalogLinksList = $('.header .category .category__item');
                var catalogItems = [];

                $catalogLinksList.each(function () {
                    catalogItems.push({
                        sectionLink: $('a.category__link', this).attr('href'),
                        sectionTitle: $('.category__title', this).text()
                    })
                });
                return catalogItems;
            })
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error while evaluating the main page', uri, err);
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            callback(null, result);
        })
        .finally(function () {
            return this.page.close();
        })
        .finally(function () {
            return this.ph.exit();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Frustrating layers of API abstraction :(

What worked for me is following the API guidelines from node-phantom:
https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node#page-object-api

PhantomJS uses `page.set(..` whereas phantomjs-node uses `page.setting(..` both to read and write.

`camelCased` for extra confusion ;)

```
  this._page.setting('userAgent', 'foobar');     

  return this._page.setting('userAgent'); // returns 'foobar'
```

I had the same issue just now, and your question helped me narrow this down. Thanks!